# Drag and drop JavaScript thumbnail generation. Browser crash due to base64 limit exceeded

Tags: javascript, image-processing

**Task:**

My task is to create  a thumbnail generator using JavaScript without additional frameworks or server side. A user drops an image to a dropzone and a thumbnail is generated and displayed onto the screen. When you click on a thumbnail the full version of image should appear in the next tab.

**Current solution:**

I have used an invisible canvas element to draw the full and resized version of the image and I am saving them by using `canvas.toDataURL()` and attach this *base64* encoding to the **img** and **a** tags.

**Problem**:

The problem I am facing is related to the file size of the image I can drop. Currently when I upload the image that exceeds 2 Megabytes  the thumbnail is generated correctly but if I want to display the full size image Chrome or Firefox crash due to base64 length limit.

**Question**:

Is there any workaround to bypass base64 lenght limit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.

You should use [HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement.toBlob) to create [Blob](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob) object, and then [URL.createObjectURL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL.createObjectURL) to create temporary URL that can be used to display image via  or for downloading image.

Also take a look at MDN articles like [Using object URLs to display images](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Using_object_URLs_to_display_images)

```js
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.fillStyle = "#FFFFFF";
ctx.font="12px Verdana";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
ctx.fillText("jpeg with",0,10);
ctx.fillText("quality 20 used",0,25);
ctx.fillText("intentionally",0,40);
ctx.moveTo(0,50);
ctx.lineTo(100,100);
ctx.stroke();
canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
 var img = document.createElement('img');
 var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 img.src = url;
 img.onload = function(){
  URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
 }
 document.body.appendChild(img);
}, "image/jpeg", 0.20);
```

```html
<p>may not work on stackoverflow, try jsfiddle in this case</p>
<canvas id="canvas" width="100" height="100"/>
```

Please note that since `canvas.toBlob` accepts callback, and calling `window.open` from callback (rather than click event) will cause window to be blocked (read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16993471/870183) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2587692/870183)).

To bypass this you can create a blob beforehand, so when click occurs you can display image instantly.